# Need help in understanding Sockets getaddrinfo

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, port, getaddrinfo

I have been trying to learn sockets programming, and came across this website: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html which is really good. I was able to understand, but after writing a test program myself I ended up with a problem which I cannot figure after 3 hours. Have very limited time, so thought asking experts help here.

This is my server program:

```
/**
 * Program showing how sockets can be used
 */

#include <stdio.h>          // For printf
#include <strings.h>        // For bzero, memset
#include <stdlib.h>         // For exit, atoi
#include <unistd.h>         // For close

#include <sys/socket.h>     // For socket
#include <sys/types.h>      // For types

#include <arpa/inet.h>      // For inet_addr
#include <netdb.h>          // Import module network database

#include <errno.h>          // To access the global errno that holds last system call error
#include <assert.h>         // For asserting

#define ADDRESSINFO_GET_SUCCESS 0
const int   kSuccess            = 0;
const char *kMyPort             = "3490"; // Can be either port num or name of the service
const int   kMaxListenConn      = 10;     // How many connections queue will hold

// Utility function to get socket address, IPv4 or IPv6:
void* getSocketAddress(const struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    // Cast socketaddr to sockaddr_in to get address and port values from data

    if (sa->sa_family == PF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

// Utility function to get socket address string
void getSocketAddressString(const struct sockaddr *sd, char *ipAddr)
{
    inet_ntop(sd->sa_family, getSocketAddress(sd), ipAddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
}

int createAndBindSocket(const struct addrinfo *addrList)
{
    int status = -1;            // Invalid status
    int socketFileDesc = -1;    // Invalid descriptor

    const struct addrinfo *addrIt;

    /*
     * STEP 2.1: Loop through all the addrinfo nodes and bind to the one we can
     */

    for (addrIt = addrList; addrIt != NULL; addrIt = addrIt->ai_next)
    {
        char ipAddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(addrIt->ai_family, getSocketAddress(addrIt->ai_addr), ipAddr, sizeof ipAddr);
        printf("IP: %s\n", ipAddr);

        /*
         * STEP 2.2: Crete the socket file descriptor for our IP address
         */

        socketFileDesc = socket(addrIt->ai_family, addrIt->ai_socktype, addrIt->ai_protocol);

        if (socketFileDesc == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create socket with error: %d\n", errno);
            perror("socket");   // Get error desc
            continue;           // Try next address
        }

        /*
         * STEP 2.3: Set socket behaviour by making ip address to be re-used if used already
         */

        int yes=1;

        if (setsockopt(socketFileDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Port %d\n",((struct sockaddr_in *)addrIt->ai_addr)->sin_port);

        /*
         * STEP 2.4: Bind our socket with ip address and port number to listen
         */

        status = bind(socketFileDesc, addrIt->ai_addr, addrIt->ai_addrlen);
        if (status != kSuccess) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bind socket with error:%d\n", errno);
            perror("bind");  // Get error desc

            // Clear socket
            close(socketFileDesc);
            socketFileDesc = -1;

            continue;       // Try next address
        }
    }

    return socketFileDesc;
}


int main()
{
    int status = -1; // Status is invalid

    struct addrinfo  hints;         // Holds our hints to get address info
    struct addrinfo *addrList;      // Contains our address info

    /*
     * STEP 1: Setup service details
     */

    // Make sure struct is empty
    bzero(&hints, sizeof hints); // memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;    // Don't care IPv4 or v6
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;  // Use TCP stream sockets
    hints.ai_flags      = AI_PASSIVE;   // Use my local IPs or you igore this and provide IP manually in first arg


    status = getaddrinfo(NULL, kMyPort, &hints, &addrList);
    if (status != kSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get address info with error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * STEP 2: Create a socket and bind it
     */

    int socketFileDesc;
    socketFileDesc = createAndBindSocket(addrList);

    freeaddrinfo(addrList);   // Done with list

    if (socketFileDesc == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * STEP 3: Listen to the port for incoming connections
     */

    status = listen(socketFileDesc, kMaxListenConn);     // Second arg is number of incoming connections in queue
    if (status != kSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to listen to the port\n");
        perror("listen");
        goto exit;
    }

    printf("Server is listening at the port %s\n", kMyPort);

    struct sockaddr_storage inConnAddr;     // Big enough to hold both IPv4 and v6
    socklen_t inConnAddrLen = sizeof inConnAddr;

    const size_t kMaxBufferSize = 50;
    char buff[kMaxBufferSize] = {0};

    long bytesReceived = -1;
    long bytesSent = 0;
    int clientSockfd;

    while (1) {

        /*
         * STEP 4: Accept incoming connections
         */

        inConnAddrLen = sizeof inConnAddr;

        clientSockfd = accept(socketFileDesc, (struct sockaddr *)&inConnAddr, &inConnAddrLen);

        // Got new connection ?
        if (clientSockfd == -1) {
            perror("accept");   // Print error description
            continue;           // Continue to look for new connections
        }

        //
        // Got connection, create child process to handle request
        //

        if (!fork()) {
            close(socketFileDesc); // No need with child

            char ipAddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
            getSocketAddressString((struct sockaddr *)&inConnAddr, ipAddr);
            printf("Child process created for hanlding request from %s\n", ipAddr);

            /*
             * STEP 5: Receive and Send data to requests
             */

            bytesReceived = recv(clientSockfd, &buff, kMaxBufferSize - 1, 0);
            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                printf("Data from client %s\n", buff);
                while (bytesSent < bytesReceived) {
                    bytesSent = send(clientSockfd, buff, bytesReceived, 0);
                    printf("Bytes sent %ld\n", bytesSent);
                }
            }

            if (bytesReceived < 0) {
                perror("recv");
            }
            else if (bytesReceived == 0) {
                printf("Connection closed by server\n");
            }

            close(clientSockfd); // Close socket
            exit(0);
        }
    }

exit:
    /*
     * STEP 5: Close the socket
     */
    close(socketFileDesc);


    return 0;
}
```

This is my client program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

const char  kSuccess = 0;

// Utility function to get socket address
void* getSocketAddress(const struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &( ((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr );
    }

    return &( ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa)->sin6_addr );
}

// Utility function to get socket address string
void getSocketAddressString(const struct sockaddr *sd, char *ipAddr)
{
    inet_ntop(sd->sa_family, getSocketAddress(sd), ipAddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
}

int createAndConnectSocket(const struct addrinfo *addrList)
{
    int socketFileDesc = -1;    // Invalid descriptor

    const struct addrinfo *addrIt;

    /*
     * STEP 2.1: Loop through all the addrinfo nodes and bind to the one we can
     */

    for (addrIt = addrList; addrIt != NULL; addrIt = addrIt->ai_next)
    {
        /*
         * STEP 2.2: Crete the socket file descriptor for our IP address
         */

        socketFileDesc = socket(addrIt->ai_family, addrIt->ai_socktype, addrIt->ai_protocol);

        if (socketFileDesc == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create socket with error: %d\n", errno);
            perror("socket");   // Get error desc
            continue;           // Try next address
        }

        /*
         * STEP 2.3: Set socket behaviour by making ip address to be re-used if used already
         */

        int yes=1;

        if (setsockopt(socketFileDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        char ipAdd[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        getSocketAddressString(addrIt->ai_addr, ipAdd);
        ((struct sockaddr_in *)addrIt->ai_addr)->sin_port = atoi("3490");

        printf("IP is %s::%d\n", ipAdd,((struct sockaddr_in *)addrIt->ai_addr)->sin_port);

        // Connect to the socket
        int status;
        status = connect(socketFileDesc, addrIt->ai_addr, addrIt->ai_addrlen);
        if (status != kSuccess) {
            perror("connect");
            close(socketFileDesc);
            socketFileDesc = -1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return socketFileDesc;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Check we have data from arguments
    if (argc < 3 || argc > 3) {
        perror("Invalid command");
        printf("Usage: %s hostname portnumber\n", argv[0]);
        printf("       %s 192.168.1.2 3490\n", argv[0]);
    }

    // Setup server address info
    struct addrinfo *serverInfo;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int status = -1;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);  // Make sure it is empty

    hints.ai_family     = AF_INET;      // IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;  // Use socket stream

    ((struct sockaddr_in *)&hints.ai_addr)->sin_port = atoi(argv[2]);

    status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "3490", &hints, &serverInfo);
    if (status != kSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get address info %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connecting to %s::%s...\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

    // Create and bind socket
    int sockfd = createAndConnectSocket(serverInfo); 

    freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);   // We are done with serverinfo

    if (sockfd == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    // Send and receive data from server

    long bytesReceived = -1;
    long bytesSent  = 0;

    const size_t kMaxBufferSize = 50;
    char buff[kMaxBufferSize];

    const char *msg = "Hi! I am client!";
    size_t msgLen = strlen(msg);

    printf("Connected to server\n");

    // Loop to send and receive data
    while (1) {

        while (bytesSent < msgLen) {
            bytesSent = send(sockfd, msg, msgLen, 0);
            printf("Bytes sent %ld\n", bytesSent);
        }

        bytesReceived = recv(sockfd, &buff, kMaxBufferSize - 1, 0);
        if (bytesReceived > 0)
        {
            printf("Data received from server: %s\n", buff);
        }
        else if (bytesReceived < 0) {
            perror("Read error");
            break;
        }
        else if (bytesReceived == 0) {
            printf("Connection closed by server\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    // Close socket
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is: Even though I have set the port and IP in getaddrinfo() call, but when it is binding or connecting the port number found in sockaddr struct is wrong as it is different value. I do know what is happing here, and I get connection refused message when I do that because of that.
Can anyone please take a look at my program and tell me why I am getting connection refused ? I would really appreciate if someone can suggest any improvements in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're not connecting to the port you think you're connecting to.

```
((struct sockaddr_in *)addrIt->ai_addr)->sin_port = atoi("3490");
```

The value of `sin_port` must be in network byte order, i.e. big endian.  You're instead assigning the value 3490 (via `atoi`) directly, so the value is in host byte order.  Your platform is most likely using little endian byte ordering.

As a result instead of connecting to port 3490 (0DA2 hex) you're connecting to port 41485 (A2 0D hex).

You need to use the `htons` function, which converts a 16 bit value (since `sin_port` is a 16 bit field) from host byte order to network byte order.  Also, there's no need to use `atoi` here.  Just use a numeric constant instead.

```
((struct sockaddr_in *)addrIt->ai_addr)->sin_port = htons(3490);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot about this, and I have corrected it but I still have problem. Now, I am getting operation timed out with connect call. Do you have any idea ? Also would you mind looking at my code and suggest any code improvements ? Thanks  PS: If I manually input sockaddr, family and other values instead of using getaddrinfo() to get structure then it connects and works fine, but does not work if I use getaddrinfo() to get the structure and use it.

Comment: @DineshG It works fine for me with server and client on the same machine.  Check your firewall settings.